# firebase android multiple event listener callBacks on static variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
discussionReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Discussion discussion = dataSnapshot.getValue(Discussion.class);
            discussionAdapter.add(discussion);
            //cancel spinner
            t[0]++;
            if(t[0]>=2)setNormalScreen();
            ObjectsKeysManager.discussionIds.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());/*this is my static variable*/
            discussionAdapter.notifyItemInserted(ObjectsKeysManager.discussionIds.size()-1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Discussion newDiscussion = dataSnapshot.getValue(Discussion.class);
            String discussionKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            int discussionIndex = ObjectsKeysManager.discussionIds.indexOf(discussionKey);
            if(discussionIndex>-1)
            {
                discussionAdapter.update(newDiscussion, discussionIndex);
                discussionAdapter.notifyItemChanged(discussionIndex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            Discussion removedDiscussion = dataSnapshot.getValue(Discussion.class);
            int index = ObjectsKeysManager.discussionIds.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            ObjectsKeysManager.discussionIds.remove(index);/*here its changed*/
            discussionAdapter.removeElement(removedDiscussion);
            discussionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

what if the user1 adds child, user2 removes child, user3 updates another child at the exact same time. Its obvious that **ObjectsKeysManager.discussionIds**  is in all . How to lock the variable **ObjectsKeysManager.discussionIds** ? or how to professionaly implement this ? 
additionally 
do **onChildAdded(), onChildChanged(), onChildRemoved()** wait for each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Alex Mamo suggested I have been studying Transaction class and transaction only helped for a single node, but in my case the big problem was to make onChildEventListener() thread safe (I dont know if it is by default but didn't take the risk) ,the solution I came up is making a method **public synchronized void onChildModified(DataSnaphot dataSnaphot, String type)** and redirected **onChildChanged()** and **onChildRemoved()** to it by passing the snapshot as parameter, this made any event that happened go directly to the synchronized method and saved the day, about the **onChildAdded()** its not necessary to make is thread safe reason being in order to *change* and *remove* the child it must be added so no need to put it inside **onChildModified()** (even if you did probably gonna have some errors because of the iteration of the snapShot).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, i recomand you using [transaction operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). This is the best way in which you can achieve this, when we are talking about concurrent modifications.

I recomand you also using `ValueEventListener` that has only one method named `onDataChange()` which reads and listens for changes to the entire contents of a specific path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you mean like transaction inside the adapter ? this will be like  `myViewHodler.buttonStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)`.... then putting it inside here ? well example will be appreciated .

Comment: On the link above, it's also an example. You can t ake a look. You can use transaction anywhere you need.